# User language support in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, internationalization, delphi-7

My program is written in **Delphi 7** and I want to avoid a Russian or a Chinese, 
Korean try to use my soft because file paths contains Unicode chars and my program can t handle them yet (as long as I do not port my program on a new Delphi version supporting UNICODE).

How do I write a function detecting the "Unicode language" in Delphi 7?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what you mean. It's not yet clear.

Comment: I want to detect which langage is used by user and if it is korean, Chinese, Russian, ... I d like to informhim that he can not use mysoft

Comment: What do you mean by "language used by user"? That could be many things. Be precise. Why would you want to block them using your sw anyway. It might work. If it doesn't work then they won't use it anyway!

Comment: Unicode can handle all languages: So it can handle Korean AND Chinese characters. So maybe you want to query the language used by windows?

Comment: yes.

if I use FileExists in my soft, it is the Ansi version in Delphi 7. 
So It will be a problem if there are Unicode strings in the path...

Comment: Then  the user just needs to restrict themselves to files in the ANSI range. No problem at all. My Delphi 6 version of my app is in use in all the countries you list plus hundreds more around the world.

Comment: @David - I remember something about if you are a registered US Government supplier of software goods you have to agree to not sell your software to China, Russia or Korea

Comment: Basically *ANY* Windows version can contain Unicode characters in path and it has nothing to do with Local OS version, nor the language that user prefers. Therefore blocking certain users from using your program won't help. Instead you should just handle Unicode (preferable way) or block non-ASCII paths.

Comment: @Cape, the American company I work for sells its software to several U.S. government agencies as well as customers in Russia and China, and I'm sure South Korea, too. But the user isn't asking about his or her customer's citizenship anyway; the question asks how to detect the language on the (false) assumption that the language controls what characters might appear in file names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Delphi 7 program (in its VCL part) can handle Russian, Chinese or Korean characters without any problem.

If the Windows system language is properly set, the [charset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) will match the corresponding encoding, and the file names will be able to have Unicode chars as available in this charset. In fact, default `string=AnsiString` is converted into Unicode when the VCL calls Windows APIs (all `....A()` calls will do the conversion then call the `....W()` version).

You can force the  [default code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) (the one which will select the charset to be used) by calling code [like this](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/09/14/L10n-and-i18n-in-our-framework):

```
if GetThreadLocale<>LCID then // force locale settings if different
  if SetThreadLocale(LCID) then
    GetFormatSettings; // resets all locale-specific variables
```

In this case, the `TFileName` (=`AnsiString`) in the current system charset will be converted by Windows into the corresponding Unicode characters, and you'll be able to use it in your Delphi 7 application.

What you can't do with the standard VCL AnsiString use it to directly *mix charsets*, as you can since Delphi 2009, thanks to the new `string = UnicodeString` default paradigm.

**PS:**

Since the CharSet only involve #128..#255 chars (i.e. all with bit 7 set), if you use only #0..#127 chars, your string will be consistent whatever the current charset/codepage setting is. If you use only English chars and numbers e.g., your path will always work, whatever the charset/codepage is. But if you use non English chars, the path will only work if the charset/codepage is correctly set, which is the case for a path used by an end-user (using a `TOpenDialog` at runtime for instance).

Comment: User, I don't think you've realized the simple fact that unicode paths occur EVERYWHERE, even in the USA.  You can either be broken exactly the same amount everywhere, or you can port upwards to a Unicode delphi version.

Comment: @user382591 FileExists() will use an TFileName=AnsiString parameter in Delphi 7, which will be converted into Unicode file name by Windows (using the current code page / charset) when searching for the file. So YES, FileExists() always uses unicode paths, depending on the current charset.